# Covisibility with QGIS/GRASS : r.los issue

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, viewshed

I try to use r.los for a viewshed calculation.

I specify the dem (Aster DEM clipped on a 2km*2km region).

I specify x and y coordinates and run the command.

Nothing append. I waited for 20 minutes without a result. The loading cursor stay at 0. No error message, no stop, nothing.

I'm using r.los in QGIS/GRASS with an 1.8 version and under Windows 7.

Do you kwno why ?

Comment: Please add if you call GRASS via the GRASS toolbox or via the Sextante plugin. Additionally you may post here how many pixels your ASTER map has.

Comment: Clearly it was the resolution. I used a 0.5 meter orthophotography to define the region...I need to decrease it but I still have problems in understanding how to change the region's resolution. There's no g.region command in QGIS so when I use the button "edit current grass region" to put 5,5, it doesn't change my raster resolution. The ortho stay at 0.5 meter.

Comment: Consider to use the Sextante plugin for using GRASS GIS within QGIS (http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Sextante) which handles the data transfer much more smoothly.

Comment: I already work sometimes with Sextante Toolbox but the thing I like in GRASS is the masking possibilities that you don't have in QGIS.

Comment: ... well, perhaps you work directly in GRASS at this point?

Comment: I wish GRASS to be more easier in QGIS in order to have the best of both software...GRASS itself on Windows 7...not so good.

Comment: @markusN -- I have tried to use Sextante plugin (now under "Processing > Commander" menu in QGIS 2.0.1) for r.los, and it is not working. It fails to open output raster file. So -- this may be a problematic solution to the problem.

Comment: In GRASS GIS 7, better use r.viewshed instead of r.los since it it 1 million (?) times faster...